# Build issue after installing react native vector icons

Tags: ios, react-native, icons

I'm trying to compile my app after installing react-native-vector and I get this error

[build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKKKt.png)

I installed it following this:

npm i react-native-vector-icons

ANDROID:
Folder Android>App>build.gradle:

```
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

IOS:
Podfile:

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

iOS folder myApp>Info.plist adding the following lines:

```
 <key>UIAppFonts</key> <array> 
<string>AntDesign.ttf</string> 
<string>Entypo.ttf</string> 
<string>EvilIcons.ttf</string> 
<string>Feather.ttf</string> 
<string>FontAwesome.ttf</string> 
<string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string> 
<string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string> 
<string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string> 
<string>Foundation.ttf</string> 
<string>Ionicons.ttf</string> 
<string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string> 
<string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string> 
<string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string> 
<string>Octicons.ttf</string> 
<string>Zocial.ttf</string> </array>
```

I used pod update and pod install

[updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqLOr.png)